# How can I parse a clist into a keyval prop?

Tags: latex3, xparse, key-value, comma-separated-list

I'm trying to store a comma-separated list into a key-value property to use it later, but I can't get it to work properly.

I don't really understand how latex parses a keyval parameter but my guess is that it's processing the parameter as plain text.

This is the code I currently have:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \getvmeta } { m } { \prop_item:cn { g_rvnlatex_doc_prop } { #1 } }
\NewDocumentCommand { \setvmeta } { m m } { \prop_gput:cnV { g_rvnlatex_doc_prop } { #1 } #2 }

\keys_define:nn { ravenhill/latex/meta } {
    author .clist_set:N = \l_rvnlatex_author_clist ,
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \setup } { m } { 
  \group_begin:
  \prop_new:c { g_rvnlatex_doc_prop }
  \keys_set:nn { ravenhill/latex/meta } { #1 }
  \setvmeta { author } { \l_rvnlatex_author_clist }
  \group_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \authorblock } { } {
  \clist_new:N \l__authblock_authcopy_clist
  \clist_set:Nn \l__authblock_authcopy_clist { \getvmeta { author } }
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l__authblock_authcopy_clist { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and~ }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
  
\setup { 
    author = {John, Bob},
}

\begin{document}
  \authorblock
\end{document}
```

The result I got is `John,Bob` instead of `John and Bob`.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Try to print out the value of l__authblock_authcopy_clist just after the clist_set command. What do you see?

Comment: Also they really need an expl3 tutorial...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess is correct.  When you use

```
\clist_set:Nn \l__authblock_authcopy_clist { \getvmeta { author } }
```

the clist parser only sees `\getvmeta { author }` which, as far as it is concerned, is no different to `getvmeta { author }`, since it has no comma in there.

To expose the comma-list you passed to the `author` key, you have to expand `\getvmeta{author}` to its contents.  To do that, use `\clist_set:Nx` (`x` means exhaustive expansion).  It will work because `\prop_item:Nn` works by expansion so it can return the item in an expansion context (you also have to allow `\getvmeta` to expand by declaring it with `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`).

Also, move the variable declarations outside user-level commands: you never know if someone will try to use, say, `\setup` twice, and if they do, your code will error when trying to declare a variable that already exists.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand { \getvmeta } { m }
  { \prop_item:Nn \g_rvnlatex_doc_prop {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \setvmeta } { m m }
  { \prop_gput:NnV \g_rvnlatex_doc_prop {#1} #2 }

\keys_define:nn { ravenhill/latex/meta }
  { author .clist_set:N = \l_rvnlatex_author_clist }

\prop_new:N \g_rvnlatex_doc_prop
\clist_new:N \l__authblock_authcopy_clist

\NewDocumentCommand \setup { m }
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { ravenhill/latex/meta } {#1}
      \setvmeta { author } { \l_rvnlatex_author_clist }
    \group_end:
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \authorblock { }
  {
    \clist_set:Nx \l__authblock_authcopy_clist { \getvmeta { author } }
    \clist_use:Nnnn \l__authblock_authcopy_clist { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ,~and~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setup{author = {John, Bob}}

\begin{document}
  \authorblock
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm somewhat reluctant on the `\prop_new:N` and `\clist_new:N` with fixed names inside `\setup` and `\authorblock`.

Comment: @Skillmon Good call.  Fixed, thanks